# Color banding on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, background-image, linear-gradients

Today I switched over to Firefox but I noticed that on my website the color gradients are banded and it looks quite ugly. [Color banding, especially noticeable in areas such as the main paragraph box, and the background (Firefox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHS0C.png) [Chrome, no banding, looks exactly as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZK7R.png)

I found a website called https://cssgradient.io/ and it seemed like instead of using background-image, they used background instead, and I could see no noticeable banding. I tried it and was expecting that there would be no visible banding, however the banding effect was still perfectly clear and nothing changed.(Before I posted this I tested setting the background color to 99% opacity and nothing changed)

Comment: are you using any dark mode extension on your firefox?@4194304

Comment: no dark mode extensions are in use all I am using is uBlock Origin and Firefox's built in dark mode, also I have absolutely no dark mode on my website, it is all in one style. the website is https://4194304.github.io if you want to test it

Comment: it is actually ok and working fine on firefox, and the result is as same as chrome, I guess the problem is either your uBlock origin or your firefox built-in firefox or maybe some extension on your pc, for getting sure about this test this on someone else pc but as I said there is nothing wrong with your website on my pc and browsers

Comment: disabled all extensions and made it use my GPU but the color banding effect still occurs

Comment: I recommend you to check your site on somebody's else computer, as I told you no problem on my pc

Comment: Same issue here. Color is beautiful in Chromium, ugly as hell on Firefox. Running Linux Mint with Nvidia drivers installed.